# Block Macs from connecting to Windows over RDP?

Tags: mac-mini, administration

Is it possible to block all remote desktop connections from a Mac to Windows? If it is, then how?

Comment: You can run Windows on a Mac... does that count as a Mac?

Comment: Also, I edited your question to remove what appeared to me to basically be repetition. If you feel I changed the intent of your question, feel free to either [edit further](http://superuser.com/posts/624475/edit) or revert the edit using the "rollback" link in [the edit history](http://superuser.com/posts/624475/revisions).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your question sounds to me a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Basically I just try to prevent users to take a remote session of any Windows servers out of our Office LAN

Comment: @user2083200 Then why not block inbound RDP on the perimeter firewall? What's to say that a system running Windows (of which there are many, many more than Macs) is by definition friendly, and Macs are by definition hostile?